# Using ajax insert html at the specified position

Tags: javascript, ajax

When scrolling goes down by 30% or when a specific position is reached
You want to insert the html document at the specified location.

Below is ajax that runs when the scroll is about 30% and html to be inserted.

html

```
<!-- Number 1 -->
    <div class="anyDiv off" data-ajax="/html/ajax/number_1.html"></div>
<!-- //Number 1 -->

<!-- Number 2 -->
    <div class="anyDiv off" data-ajax="/html/ajax/number_2.html"></div>
<!-- //Number 2 -->
```

javascript

```
$(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(e){
    var bodyHeight = $('body').height();
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop()+$(window).height();
    var per = Math.ceil((scrollTop/bodyHeight)*100);

    if( per >= 30 ){
      $('.anyDiv.off').each(function(){
        var pop_ax = $(this);
        var load_url = $(this).data('ajax');

        $(this).removeClass('off');

        $.ajax({
          url:load_url,
          type:'get',
          dataType : 'html',
          success:function(data){
            pop_ax.append($("<div class='remove'/>").html(data).find('.loadhtml').html());
          }
        });

        return false;
      });
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

[number_1.html]

```
<div class="loadhtml">
    <div ax="main">
        <div class="bg-grey">            
            <h2 class="main-letter"><strong>#Number1</strong></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[number_2.html]

```
<div class="loadhtml">
    <div ax="main">
        <div class="bg-grey">            
            <h2 class="main-letter"><strong>#Number2</strong></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I wonder if you can call number_1.html and number_2.html faster with ajax like above.

Or, can we call sequentially number_1.html> number_2.html sequentially?

Note: number_1.html, number_2.html Contains dynamic data.

Comment: What do you mean by "speed up"?  What are you trying to do and/or what isn't working the way you expect?

Comment: @WillardSolutions I wonder if you can call number_1.html and number_2.html faster with ajax like above. Or, can we call sequentially number_1.html> number_2.html sequentially?

Comment: Do the number_1.html and number_2.html have dynamic content or something which executes when they load ? because if not, you can include them in the DOM hidden and show them when needed using CSS, it will be much faster for sure.

Comment: @drinu16 number_1.html, number_2.html Contains dynamic data.

Comment: It still isn't clear what you're asking. By "loading faster", do you mean you want these to load when the page loads instead of when user scrolls down the page?  Are you saying the network load time is too slow? Is the 30% figure what you want to change?  Please help me understand  your question

Comment: @WillardSolutions 30% is the scrolling number of the page.If the page goes down by 30%, then we are loading it.Can I "load faster" when I scroll down the page? Network load time seems to be too slow.